# i loose hotdeploy jboss capabilities

Tags: maven-2, jboss7.x

the client wants to change the url pattern to access the webproject , when i add a `<warname>newname</warname>` in maven-war-plugin , my newname.war is generated but i  lose the jboss hotdeploy capabilities  .

eventhough i'm not quitte sure , but i think jboss uses the default project name to generate a war en explode it for hotdeploy .

can you advice me a solution to change the url of the project to newname/page.xhtml istead of oldName/page.xhtml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a matter of changing the WAR context, just add a jboss-web.xml file inside your WAR /WEB-INF/ directory, with such contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>          
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>newname</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Doing this for other app servers would require the use of other files of course.